# Change WebSphere's default Java SDK from IBM's JVM to Oracle's?

Tags: java, websphere

I've seen mentions that it's possible to change WebSphere 8.x so that it uses Oracle's JVM instead of IBM's included JVM. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

It does [seem possible](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/10826/liberty-8-5-5-1-running-under-oracle-jvm-bad-idea.html) but I did not see a method mentioned anywhere that shows how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible/supported in the traditional/classic/full profile of WebSphere.

Under what's called the "Liberty Profile" you simply set JAVA_HOME to your oracle JRE.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?

Comment: Well, there's an environment variable called JAVA_HOME that applications traditionally use to find a non-bundled java.  Liberty uses it and is supported with any contemporary java runtime, not just IBM java.  Try it and see?

Comment: Sorry I meant how do I utilize the Liberty Profile. I'm new to WAS and have been learning about as I go.

Comment: It's actually much less intimidating, you can download it as a small ~60MB jar from wasdev.net (it's also included in your tradtional WAS base/ND media).  The same site has a bunch article and links to github that show some starter/sample projects. Finally, you can use it real easily on BlueMix, IBM's PaaS based on cloud foundry (similar to heroku)